# Limit Mac app Beta usage to selection of UDID-approved devices

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I have a Mac app I just created in Xcode, and signed as a "Mac App Store" application, with the default Team Provisioning Profile. I only have two UDIDs registered in the Member Center, and can run the application on any of my devices (expected)... but ALSO on any other non-registered devices.

Is there a way to lock the application to only registered UDIDs for the purpose of Beta testing?

The documentation seems to apply mostly to iOS applications, and remains a little unclear for the Mac application procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I wasn't able to sign my code with my UDID-specific Provisioning Profile at all in Xcode. However, by setting the Provisioning Profile to my restricted one, and properly setting my Code Signing Identity, I was able to compile via command-line properly.

Now when loaded on any machine other then the UDID-approved ones, the application fails to launch (which is the desired behavior for my Beta testing strategy).